# How to devide my dataset for using permanova

Tags: r, dataset, permutation

Hello everyone :) I have a data set with individuals that correspond in 5 different species in one column, and their presence/absence in different landscapes (7 other columns).

```
data.frame':    1212 obs. of  10 variables:
$ latitude   : num  34.5 34.7 34.7 34.8 34.8 ...
$ longitude  : num  127 127 127 127 127 ...
$ species    : Factor w/ 5 levels "Bufo gargarizans",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
$ Built      : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
$ Agriculture: int  1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 ...
$ Forested   : int  0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 ...
$ Grassland  : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
$ Wetland    : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
$ Bare       : int  0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 ...
$ Water      : int  1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 ...
```

I try to use permanova and then Tukey test to see if the species use the landscape differently or not. My supervisor did it on SPSS and it worked very well, so I have to do it on R.

I saw I need 2 csv files for running permanova on R but I have only one. I will give you the script that I found on internet and I want to use for my analysis.

```
library(vegan)
data(dune)
data(dune.env)
# default test by terms
adonis2(dune ~ Management*A1, data = dune.env)
```

In my case, I should have 1 dataframe with species and 1 dataframe with environmental variables, if I understand well.
However my presence/absence are inside the environmental categories (see the str of my table above). So if I create 1 dataframe with species only, I will not have numerical values in the dataframe with species.

So I am totally lost. I don't know how to process. Can someone help me please ? Thank you !

Comment: it's hard to help you without more specific information and a minimal working example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Hello, thank you! I have improved my question. I hope it is better

Answer (score 0):

I will split my answer into two parts. The one where I know what I am talking about and one where I am brainstorming ;)

Here is the first part on how to split your data into two data.frames

```
# Set seed
seed(1312)
# Some sample data
sample_data <- dplyr::tibble(species=sample(LETTERS[1:5],size=500,replace=T),
                   Built=sample(c(0,1),size=500,replace=T),
                   Agriculture=sample(c(0,1),size=500,replace=T),
                   Forested=sample(c(0,1),size=500,replace=T),
                   Grassland=sample(c(0,1),size=500,replace=T),
                   Wetland=sample(c(0,1),size=500,replace=T),
                   Bare=sample(c(0,1),size=500,replace=T),
                   Water=sample(c(0,1),size=500,replace=T))

# Split data
df1 <- sample_data %>%
  dplyr::select(species)
df2 <- sample_data %>%
  dplyr::select(Built:Water)
```

Now part two: as it says in `?adonis2` the first part of adnonis2 is a formula where the left part of the formula must be a community data matrix or a dissimilarity matrix

Eventhough I am not sure if it does make sense, I went wild and followed the instructions :D

```
df2_dist <- dist(df2)
vegan::adonis2(df2_dist~species, data=df1) 

Permutation test for adonis under reduced model
Terms added sequentially (first to last)
Permutation: free
Number of permutations: 999

vegan::adonis2(formula = d2 ~ species, data = d1)
         Df SumOfSqs      R2      F Pr(>F)
species   4    5.333 0.15802 0.7038   0.88
Residual 15   28.417 0.84198              
Total    19   33.750 1.00000
```

Of course this might be nonsense in terms of content as I took a purely technical approach here, but maybe it helps you to shape your data as required

Comment: Thank you so much !!!! I ran it but why the table of my species is like this : 
A
E
C
E
C
E
B.....
?
Whereas I have the same species for the first 200 observations...

Comment: I had no access to your data. That's why I created a fake dataset. The content of the dataset does not matter, because it's random. I just created it to show how you could split your file ...

Comment: Thank you very much :) 
I'll follow your example !

Comment: you're welcome. but be careful with the second part ... adonis2 seems to require a distance matrix, but I am not quite sure if a distance matrix of TRUE/FALSE makes sense ...

Comment: I try but I can't make it :(

Comment: what exactely is the problem?

Comment: I wrote a comment up :)

Answer (score 0):

So I made this code :

```
setwd("C:/Users/Johan/Downloads/memoire Johanna (1)/memoire Johanna")
xdata=read.csv(file="all10_reduce_focal species1.csv", header=T, sep=",")
str(xdata)
xdata$species <- as.factor(xdata$species)

sample_data <- dplyr::tibble(species=sample(LETTERS[1:5],size=1212,replace=T),
                         Built=sample(c(0,1),size=1212,replace=T),
                         Agriculture=sample(c(0,1),size=1212,replace=T),
                         Forested=sample(c(0,1),size=1212,replace=T),
                         Grassland=sample(c(0,1),size=1212,replace=T),
                         Wetland=sample(c(0,1),size=1212,replace=T),
                         Bare=sample(c(0,1),size=1212,replace=T),
                         Water=sample(c(0,1),size=1212,replace=T))

library(dplyr)
df1 <- sample_data %>%
       dplyr::select(species)
df2 <- sample_data %>%
       dplyr::select(Built:Water)
df1_dist <- dist(df1)

vegan::adonis2(df1_dist~Built+Agriculture+Grassland+Forested+Wetland+Bare+Water, data=df2)
```

Species should be the response as I try to see the landscape on the species. When I do this I have :

```
Error in vegdist(as.matrix(lhs), method = method, ...) : input data must be numeric
```

It's because the "species" variable has only characters. So I changed to make it numeric :

```
sample_data <- dplyr::tibble(species=sample(c(1:5),size=1212,replace=T),
                         Built=sample(c(0,1),size=1212,replace=T),......
```

But the result I got is different as the result from SPSS, as I don't have any significant variable (in SPSS Built, Agriculture, Forested and Water are significant).
I think my code is wrong